# using juju with elastic block storage ( EBS )

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

Is there a way we can use EBS for ec2 instance with juju. And possibility of scaling the storage after the deployment,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this the thing you looking for. Just look at it.
http://ceph.com/dev-notes/deploying-ceph-with-juju/
  and link below also you will need after Ceph charm deployment.
http://www.webmastersessions.com/how-to-attach-ebs-volume-to-amazon-ec2-instance

P.s. no hard feelings just trying to help.